# Unable to protect drop down list in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a drop down list and I want to protect the cell's data from being erased or written over but I still want the drop down list to work.

When I protect it, You can't use the drop down list to select anything at all.  Yes I've tried unselecting protect in format cell then protecting sheet...you are still able to erase or input different text.  I've tried merging adjacent cell as another user suggested & I am not familiar with code but I even tried inputting code that someone suggested on other blogs. Nothing works. PLEASE HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

You are going the wrong way. If you protect from changes, it cannot be changed.

What you are looking for is [Data Validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249). You can make it so it will only accept values from a Range or List, and even allow or not to leave the cells blank.